# Trying to work with multiple WHERE command in mysql query [Not Working]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have a database where I want to change the status of a certain table's row value if my query string matches with my specified table's column value..

Here's what I did so far..

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "creative_db", "samplepassword");
$db = mysql_select_db("creative_dbgogo", $connection);

$slct = mysql_query("UPDATE zombie_links SET link_status = 'discard' WHERE link_url = '%pills%' OR link_url_title = '%pills%' OR link_title = '%pills%' OR link_title_url = '%pills%' OR link_content = '%pills%' OR link_summary = '%pills%' OR link_tags= '%pills%' ") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?? Please help!

Comment: You don't say what the problem is that you experiencing.

Comment: @arkyc The problem is that no errors are being displayed and neither is the thing working on my database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` doesn't take wildcards.  I think you want `like`:

```
UPDATE zombie_links
    SET link_status = 'discard'
    WHERE link_url like '%pills%' OR link_url_title like '%pills%' OR link_title like '%pills%' OR
          link_title_url like '%pills%' OR link_content like '%pills%' OR
          link_summary like '%pills%' OR link_tags like '%pills%';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$slct = mysql_query("UPDATE zombie_links SET link_status = 'discard' WHERE link_url like '%pills%' OR link_url_title like '%pills%' OR link_title like '%pills%' OR link_title_url like '%pills%' OR link_content like '%pills%' OR link_summary like '%pills%' OR link_tags like '%pills%' ") or die(mysql_error());
```